# Var vs IEnumerable when it comes to Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

If I were to use **IEnumerable** instead of **var** in the code example below, will the SQL be generated only during the execution of the foreach statement? Or will it execute as an when the Linq statements are evaluated?

```
var query = db.Customers.Where (c => c.Age > 18);
query = query.Where (c => c.State == "CO");
var result = query.Select (c => c.Name);

foreach (string name in result)   // Only now is the query executed!
   Console.WriteLine (name);
```

Another example:

```
IEnumerable<Order> query = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Amount > 1000);
int orderCount = query.Count();
```

Would it be better to use var (or IQueryable) as it would be executed a select count(*)... when .Count() is executed or would it be exactly same with the IEnumerable code shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the SQL is generated when GetEnumerator is called on the IQueryable.

In your example, there is a subtle difference that you may want to consider. Let's take your original example:

```
var query = db.Customers.Where (c => c.Age > 18); 
query = query.Where (c => c.State == "CO"); 
var result = query.Select (c => c.Name);
```

In this case if you change your first query to IEnumerable query = ..., then the second line would use the IEnumerable version of the Where extension (LINQ to Objects) rather than the IQueryable one (LINQ to SQL/EF). As a result, when we start iterating, the first where clause is passed to the database, but the second where clause is performed on the client side (because it has already been converted to an IEnumerable).

Another subtle item you want to be aware of is the following type of code:

```
var query = db.OrderBy(c => c.State);
query = query.Customers.Where(c => c.Age > 18); // Fails: Widening
```

In this case, since your original query returns IOrderedQueryable rather than IQueryable. If you try to then assign query to the result of the .Where operation, you're trying to widen the scope of the return type and the compiler will refuse to perform that widening. As a result, you have to explicitly specify the baseline type rather than using var:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = db.OrderBy(c => c.State);  // Is narrowing rather than widening.
query = query.Customers.Where(c => c.Age > 18);
```

Comment: The second part of your answer doesn't seem right, or am I missing something? Is `db` not a type of `DataContext`?

Comment: db Is the data context, but the type that's important here is the type for the "query" variable. In the first on, it is IOrderedQueryable<T> and the second it's just IQueryable<T> due to the explicit type declaration.

Answer (score 4):

It would make no difference. `var` is just syntactic sugar. If you hover over `var`, you will see what type C# thinks your query is.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. The following two declarations of i are functionally equivalent:

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

---

If you want to perform actions on your query that SQL wouldn't know what to do with, such as a method defined in your class, then you could use `AsEnumerable()`.

For example:

```
var query = db.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Age > 18)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => GetCustomerViewModel());

//put definition of GetCustomerViewModel() somewhere in the same class
```

---

**Update**

As Omar mentioned, if you want your query to be executed immediately (rather than deferred), use `ToList()`. This will immediately enumerate the IQueryable/IEnumerable and fill the list with the actual data from the database.

Comment: In the 2nd code sample, doesn't Linq know not to execute `GetCustomerViewModel`? I just tested the code without `.AsEnumerable()` in LinqPad and it executed fine.

Comment: @Omar, did you test in LinqPad using an Entity Framework DbContext?

Answer (score 2):

Linq queries return `IQueryable<>` or `IEnumerable<>`, the execution of both is deferred.

As `DanM` stated, whether or not you use `var` or `IEnumerable<>` it all depends on the return value of the method you're calling: if it's an `IEnumerable<>` or `IQuerable<>` it'll be deferred, if you use `.ToList()`, it'll be executed right away.

When to use `var` comes down to personal choice/style. I generally use `var` when the return value is understood from the line of code and variable name or if I'm instantiating a generic with a long declartion, e.g. `Dictionary<string, Func<Order, object>>`.

From your code, it's clear that a collection of `Customers`/`Orders` is returned, so I would use the `var` keyword. Again, this is a matter of personal preference.